# Embed a centered, mobile ready video on the page?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can't seem to find any good resources on having a video embed that works well for Bootstrap. Here is the page www.costoffashion.org. It's my first Bootstrap project and frankly I find it wholly unintuitive so I'm at a loss. Any help would be appreciated. The problem with the current site is that on mobile it looks bad, the video screws up the whole page.

Comment: as far as I can see you're assigning a lot of fixed CSS values that make it look good on a desktop,  and overriding stuff that boostrap does.  I would suggest having a quick google for "bootstrap responsive iframe" or similar, since that's ultimately what you're looking for.

Comment: Ah you're totally right, the solution wasn't working because I have an outdated bootstrap. Fail. Thank you!